# How to theme webform component?

Tags: theming, forms, webforms

I want to change the order of a webform component. This creation of a webform component:

```
$component = array(
      'name' => key($question_name),
      'form_key' => $key,
      'type' => $form_type,
      'mandatory' => 0,
      'weight' => $weight,
      'pid' => 0,
      'extra' => array(
          "items" => "1|1\n2|2\n3|3\n4|4",
          "multiple " => FALSE,
          "aslist" => FALSE,
          "description" => $question['description'],
        ),
);
```

Gives me the following display result:

1. Name of component
2. 1 - 4 radiobuttons
3. Descriptiontext

But I want to move the description text over the radiobuttons:

1. Name of component
2. Descriptiontext
3. 1 - 4 radiobuttons

How can I change the order of the output?

Answer (score 0):

What I was searching for was:

`function THEMENAME_webform_element($variables)`

https://drupal.org/node/1157306